# set feild to "1" for a certain string

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to set a field to "1" depending on whether the name has "LC" at the beginning, but my syntax doesn't appear to be right

```
SET @r_sql = '  UPDATE  mytables'+@r_mystuf+'
                SET     feild1= ''1''
                WHERE   category = ''4''
                AND name LIKE ''LC%';                       

exec (@r_sql);
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the columns really called feild1 or is that a typo? Is category a string? Is Field1 a string? Why is LC% not ending with a double apostrophe? If you select the value, you should see why it's formatted incorrectly.

Comment: also, what is `@r_mystuf`? is that part of the table name? and you need some extra quotes on the end

Comment: You are missing single quote after `'LC%`. It should be `..........''LC%'''`

Comment: Sorry just ignore the field1 and @r_stuff is these are referenced elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT` instead of `LIKE`

Instead of `LIKE ''LC%'` use `LEFT(name, 2) = 'LC'`

And as mentioned quotation marks need to be sorted out.

Comment: Edited. Solution of answer still valid and correct.

Answer (score 0):

as a whole string it would be

```
set @r_sql = 'update tablename' + @r_mystuf +  ' set field1 = ' + '1' + ' where category = ' + '4' + ' and name like '''  +'LC%' +'''';
```

same thing is working with my AdventureWorks DB

```
declare @var nvarchar(121);
declare @r_mystuf nvarchar(11);
declare @mystuf nvarchar(11);
set @r_mystuf = 'Person';

set @var = N'update Person.' + @r_mystuf +  ' set PersonType = ' + 'EE' + ' where BusinessEntityID = ' + '1' + ' and FirstName like '''  +'ke%' +'''';
print  @var;
```